# What happens to existing reputation when an answer is converted to community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

This refers to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/507658/18573) which accounts for about a fourth of my total reputation.

As much as I am grateful for all who voted and want to hold on to the reputation it has already been awarded, I would like to not have any more reputation from the answer.

Will converting it to community wiki remove my reputation from the answer or just prevent new upvotes giving me more reputation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any reputation earned on the answer prior to CW conversion is preserved.