# Will I lose reputation from an accepted answer if I mark it Community Wiki?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, community-wiki

I have a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858476/java-cmyk-to-rgb-values-converter/34858802#34858802) that I'd like to mark as Community Wiki; it provides useful formulas that might come in handy to other users.  I know from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266422/what-happens-to-existing-reputation-when-an-answer-is-converted-to-community-wik) that reputation from upvotes made prior to a post becoming community wiki is preserved.  However, the reputation from my answer comes from it being an accepted answer, and not from upvotes.

So, will my 15 reputation from the accepted answer be preserved when I mark it as Community Wiki?

Comment: What does it matter? That question was a duplicate of another. Why do you want to make it CW anyway?

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right.  None of those are CW, though, and I think that the formulas should be freely available for reference, and people should be able to make corrections to them.  Also, the example on the other question was long and complicated, so this one should be more accessible.

Comment: If the answer really adds something that isn't in the duplicate, why not add it as an answer there

Comment: I think you're missing the point of community wiki. Community wiki is to be used when a post is the work of multiple users. The license is still cc-by-sa with attribution required.

Answer (score 4):

You won't lose any reputation you've gained prior to making the post community wiki, but it will look like it on your tags page. For example, compare:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/251685/?tab=tags

to:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/251685/?tab=reputation